# Spring boot with vaadin run jetty even though I use tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I try to use Spring boot with Vaadin 7.7.0. By default, spring boot use tomcat if I don not specify. However, I found there is a log as below:

```
2016-08-26 12:08:49.897  INFO 3240 --- [           main] e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2016-08-26 12:08:49.900  INFO 3240 --- [           main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server          : jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
```

I check the dependency through eclipse and there is no jetty.

Here is the dependency for the problem

How could a such strong version come?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After checking by remove I found that the wrong jetty comes from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

After remove it can add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Everything works fine.

I don't know what happened to this package. Is it any dependency conflict?

Comment: how do you run it? jetty might just be a (transient) dependency of the way you are running it.

Comment: Hi @cfrick I just find out the problem comes from `<artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>` after remove it, everything work.

Comment: oh right, it is only used to create a widgetset for you (which some maven plugin should do anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Jetty is used for the Push feature of Vaadin and is already included.

Comment: This jetty come from `<artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>`